# Extracting gene IDs for loci with R

Tags: r, annotations

I have several 100 genomic regions with start end positions. I want to extract gene IDs in each region from the reference file (reference file contains thousands of genes with their start end position). I extracted region information of genes, for example, output file tells me if a gene is present in region one or two and so on. However, each region contains many genes and there are several genes that lie in multiple regions. I want an output file that would put the IDs of all the genes in a cell next to that region (each gene ID separated by comma). If a gene is present in multiple regions, it would appear in multiple cells corresponding to those regions along with other genes of that region. Can this be done with an R code? Please help.

## Sample input.

## RegionInfoFile

```
Region  Chr Start   End
1   1A  1   12345
2   1A  23456   34567
3   2A  1234    23456
***
1830 7D 123     45678
```

## GeneInfoFile

```
Gene    Chr Start   End
GeneID1 1A  831 1437
GeneID2 1A  1487    2436
GeneID3 1B  2665    5455
***
GeneID10101 7D  13456  56789
```

## RequiredOutPutFile

```
Region  Chr Start   End   Gene
1       1A  1       12345 GeneID1, GeneID2, GeneID5, GeneID6 ***
***
1830    7D  123     45689 GeneID7, GeneID100, GeneID200 ***
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick: I have edited the question. Please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is typically accomplished via the excellent [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package on Bioconductor. You can create `GenomicRanges` objects from regions and find where they overlap using the `findOverlaps()` function. To control what counts as an overlap see the "type" argument in `findOverlaps(..., type="")`. Here's an example of that in R. I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing this but that's what I cam up with during lunch:

```r
# install.packages('readr')
library(readr)
# install.packages('BiocManager')
# BiocManager::install('GenomicRanges')
library(GenomicRanges)

# Read data into R. Needs to have column names "chr", "start" and "end"
x <- read_csv('~/Downloads/regions.csv')
y <- read_csv('~/Downloads/genes.csv')

# Set up two GenomicRanges objects
gr_x <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(x, keep.extra.columns = TRUE)
gr_y <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(y, keep.extra.columns = TRUE)

# Overlap the regions containing genes with the trait data
ovl <- findOverlaps(gr_y, gr_x, type = "any", select = "all", ignore.strand = TRUE)
# Group hits by trait regions
hits_by_region <- split(from(ovl), to(ovl))

# Create a data.frame that matches a trait region index to a string of genes
hits_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(hits_by_region), function(f) {
  idx <- as.integer(names(hits_by_region[f]))
  genes <- gr_y$Gene[hits_by_region[[f]]]
  data.frame(Index = idx, Genes = paste(genes, collapse=','), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))

# Add the string of genes as metadata to the GRanges object
gr_x$Genes <- ""
gr_x$Genes[hits_df$Index] <- hits_df$Genes

# Convert back to data.frame (if needed)
genes_by_regio_df <- as.data.frame(gr_x)
```